Completed Daisy Seed Guitar Pedal
This thread is a follow up to this one, and hopefully the last one in my series of questions.
The context is: I'd like to make a guitar pedal based on an Electrosmith Daisy Seed.
Requirements are to match standard guitar pedal specs:

1MOhm input impedance
Tolerate 10dBV (9V p2p) input signals
Deliver 10dBV (9V p2p) output signals
Deliver 10kOhm output impedance

This way the device behaves, looks, and quacks like a guitar pedal. It will also guarantee the integrity of the guitar tone (especially the impedance requirements).
Challenges to overcome are:

Daisy Seed ADCs are +1.8V/-1.8V and 5V tolerant
Daisy Seed DACs are 1Vrms (2.8V p2p)
Daisy Seed ADC input impedance is in the 10kOhm to 30kOhm range
Daisy Seed DAC output impedance is 100R

To address the challenges I've used two OPA1678 op-amps suited for audio applications based on friendly advice from this forum, in inverting amplifier configuration.
The first one to scale down the signal and provide 1MOhm input impedance, and the second one to scale up the signal and provide 10kOhm output impedance. Here is the diagram:

Two things to notice about my circuit:

I scale down the signal further with a 0.37 ratio and I scale up a little less with a 2.6 ratio because the OPA1678 can output signals between Vee + 0.8 and Vcc - 0.8 only.
You will see an ESP32 in the diagram as well: it's the Adafruit Huzzah ESP32 WROOM I plan to use it to control the Daisy Seed wirelessly, and not have any knobs on the pedal.

Here is where I am riddled with self-doubt, and would greatly appreciate answer to these questions:

The output resistors R9 and R10, I took the example of this
Terrarium output circuit and guessed how to adjust it. I looked
at R4 and R6 from that reference circuit and tried to figure out
what to do to achieve 10kOhm output. I'm not even sure what R6 does
in the original circuit, googling around got me to "pull-down
resistor" but it was always in the context of logical circuit, and
not of analog signals. Any insight there would be greatly
appreciated !
Does the output stage inverting amplifier need to have R5 = 1MOhm impedance as well ? I just copy pasted the input stage, and looked at the Terrarium circuit which seemed to also use 1MOhm.
I hope it's OK to use the same 5V from the LM7805 linear convertor to power the Adafruit Huzzah ESP32 as well as the OPA1678. I could otherwise use the separate buck converter recommended by Adafruit.
I hope I can just connect the GPIOs of the Daisy Seed and Adafruit Huzzah like that, it seems they both operate on 3.3V logic, and my plan is to pass MIDI between them, it's lazy but it simplifies things as I intend to use touchOSC2MIDI and will add MIDI IN and MIDI OUT to the ESP32.

Thank you very much for all the help, I hope sharing the progress of my project also helps other people out there looking to build something similar.

10k output impedance is high. You should aim for less than 1 kohm.

Hello. Thank you for your feedback ! I am not an electronic specialist, as it's easy to tell, and because I don't know what I am doing I just try to do like everybody else. And so it seems that 10kOhm output for guitar pedals is standard. Is there a technical reason why they can't make it less, or they won't make it less than 10kOhm ?

10k output impedance is fine. Guitars with active pickups have similar output impedance. If the output will be fed to a high-input-impedance amplifier (e.g. valve amps or USB audio interfaces) it's fine.

Thanks ! As noted, the next device in the chain is expected to have 1MOhm impedance. Does my circuit achieve 10kOhm output impedance ? I think it is achieved by R9 and R10, but I'm not sure what each does.

it has closer to 9 kiloohm impedance, you could substute 11k in for R9 to get it closer to 10k but 9k is probably close enough.

ESP32 uses quite a lot of power, it will kill your 9V batteries,

Thank you very much Jasen ! I forgot to mention somewhere that I would use a 9V power adapter. This would have 1A available. I think the ESP32 needs 0.25A budgeted for it (I read in the manual somewhere), I hope the 0.75A remaining can power everything else. Regarding impedance: ok ! Do you know if my value for R10 is correct and what it is for ? I just copied from another circuit and don't know why I did it.

This thread did not get any answer, and I am not sure if the reason is because of lack of interest, or simply because this circuit is fine and will work.
I talked to a colleague who is savvy with electronics and what came out of our discussion with regards to my questions was:

He confirmed R10 is a pulldown resistor, but he was skeptical about its usefulness
I forgot to ask him about R5, I am still unsure if it has to be 1MOhm
He said there shouldn't be a problem if I use the same power supply for the Huzzah and the Op-amp
I mentioned in passing the GPIOs and he didn't make any objections, not sure if he thought about it deeply however

So my guess is that this circuit is okay, and if nobody objects, I would then validate this as an answer.
